# write rasters from estudm2spixdf with significant digits

Tags: raster, stack

I have estimated my kernels using kernelUD from the adehabitatHS package which produces information from multiple animals as a class estUDm.  I am trying to write out from R to get into ArcGIS the raster from each of the animals.

```
myrkde <- kernelUD(mytrial[,1], h="href", same4all=T, grid=200, extent = 0.2)
```

So, I turn the kernelUD into a spixdf

```
b <- estUDm2spixdf(myrkde)
```

Only, I want a raster of each animal so I thought to stack the SPIXDF and then write each out.

```
rastyrday <- stack(b)
writeRaster(rastyrday, filename=paste("MooseYrHR", names(b)) , format="raster", bylayer=T, overwrite=T)
```

The problem is when I write out the raster, ArcGIS says Invalid raster dataset. Failed to create raster layer.  So I change the format to "img" file...OR I change format as "ascii".  Both of these produce something that ArcGIS can read/visualize - **however**, the next problem is that the values are all sooooo small that ArcGIS only registers each value as 0. When I use ArcGIS to look at the pixel values it tells me the value is 0.000000, though the max value is  often x*10^-7.  Basically, its cutting off after 6 significant digits and my values are 7 to 9.

If I writeRaster and format to ascii, the output indicates min and max values are all NA

```
writeRaster(rastyrday, filename=paste("atesttest", names(b)) , format="ascii", type = "Float32", bylayer=T, overwrite=T)
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 200, 138, 27600, 29  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 159.6563, 159.6563  (x, y)
extent      : 1470049, 1492082, 6602809, 6634741  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
names       : atesttest_Aug2010_F07002_1, atesttest_Aug2010_F07002_2, atesttest_Aug2010_F07002_3, atesttest_Aug2010_F07002_4, atesttest_Aug2010_F07002_5, atesttest_Aug2010_F07002_6, atesttest_Aug2010_F07002_7, atesttest_Aug2010_F07002_8, atesttest_Aug2010_F07002_9, atesttest//_F07002_10, atesttest//_F07002_11, atesttest//_F07002_12, atesttest//_F07002_13, atesttest//_F07002_14, atesttest//_F07002_15, ... 
min values  :                         NA,                         NA,                         NA,                         NA,                         NA,                         NA,                         NA,                         NA,                         NA,                    NA,                    NA,                    NA,                    NA,                    NA,                    NA, ... 
max values  :                         NA,                         NA,                         NA,                         NA,                         NA,                         NA,                         NA,                         NA,                         NA,                    NA,                    NA,                    NA,                    NA,                    NA,                    NA,
```

If I writeRaster as "raster" or "HFA" at least the min/max values are indicated - but still I get the failed to create raster when using the raster output type or 0's when converting to the image.

```
writeRaster(rastyrday, filename=paste("atesttest", names(b)) , format="HFA", type = "Float32", bylayer=T, overwrite=T)
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 200, 138, 27600, 29  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 159.6563, 159.6563  (x, y)
extent      : 1470049, 1492082, 6602809, 6634741  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
names       : atesttest_Aug2010_F07002_1, atesttest_Aug2010_F07002_2, atesttest_Aug2010_F07002_3, atesttest_Aug2010_F07002_4, atesttest_Aug2010_F07002_5, atesttest_Aug2010_F07002_6, atesttest_Aug2010_F07002_7, atesttest_Aug2010_F07002_8, atesttest_Aug2010_F07002_9, atesttest//_F07002_10, atesttest//_F07002_11, atesttest//_F07002_12, atesttest//_F07002_13, atesttest//_F07002_14, atesttest//_F07002_15, ... 
min values  :                          0,                          0,                          0,                          0,                          0,                          0,                          0,                          0,                          0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0, ... 
max values  :               2.351000e-07,               4.006146e-07,               6.310832e-07,               3.072779e-07,               2.306967e-07,               2.216463e-07,               2.233004e-07,               2.483713e-07,               4.006146e-07,          2.593051e-07,          1.439714e-07,          1.587329e-07,          2.105937e-07,          2.340155e-07,          2.380073e-07, ...
```

if I convert the estUDm2spixdf to a raster before stacking -

```
b <-raster(estUDm2spixdf(myrkde))
```

It only writes the very first animal - all other animals "layers" are lost. And I still end up with the same problem of the outputs either being invalid or 0's for pixel values.

How do I get each animal's UD out of adehabitatHS?  Or how do I get the ascii/img files to have significant digits small enough to recognize that there are values in the raster layer? or how do I get the raster file output to be recognized in ArcGIS?

I have posted this question to the ade4 listserve, but because writewRaster is not part of their "thing" I thought I would try here too.  As some of these commands come from the sp package and the raster package.

Im using R 3.0 and ArcGIS 10.2